# How to lock a package to not be updated or reinstalled in CentOS

Tags: linux, centos, yum

I've already installed a patched version of a package, and I don't want it be updated or reinstalled in any case.

What I have tried but not success:

- using `exclude=package-name*` in `/etc/yum.conf`: I can still yum reinstall package-name.rpm
- using `yum versionlock package-name`: same as above, I can still yum reinstall package-name.rpm

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Can you explicitely state the command `yum versionlock pacakge-name` you used? Did it include the version number? Is it shown in `yum versionlock list`?

Comment: I used `yum versionlock ceph-base`. and `versionlock list` result: `ceph-base-2:16.2.13-0.el8.*`

Comment: I download a package without my patch and with the same version to test it: 
`yum reinstall ceph-base-16.2.13-0.el8.x86_64.rpm`. and it's still allowed to reinstall

Comment: I see that the version numbers are identical. Versionlock means locking the version and allow no newer versions. This would not include reinstalling the same version e.g. for repairing a broken install.

Comment: oh I understand. Do you know any way to prevent reinstalling the same version, like in this case?

Comment: when you build your patched rpm try setting the version to `ceph-base-16.2.13-1` and then apply the versionlock.

Comment: sounds good. I will try it